# Binary Tree find height of a specific Node

Tags: height, binary-tree

Hello guys I am stack somewhere so this is my question...

I got the following binary tree class

```
public class BTree
{
   private TreeNode root;
   int i = 0;
   /////////////////////
   public BTree()
   {
      root = null;
   }
}
```

and my TreeNode class

```
public class TreeNode
{
    private TreeNode left; //consider public
    private int number;   //
    private TreeNode right; //////////////////
    //////////////////////
    public TreeNode(int number)
    {
      this.number = number;
      left = null;
      right = null;
    }
    ....
}
```

and I need to build a method that could count Tree height till a specific data 
inside a Node. For Example: int height = tree.height(5);
(to find the height of the Node that contains number 5)

I am in the part :

```
public int height(int number)
{
    return countHeight(root, number);
}
private int countHeight(TreeNode node, int number)
{
    if(node != null && node.getNumber() == number)
      return 0;
    return //what should I write here?
}
```

Recursive methods is a little hard for me so I would like
a little help over here.

Thnx in advance...

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote this code and it seems to work properly.

If you got any better solution feel free to share.

```
public int height(int number) /// it could be Object 
{
    return countHeight(root, number);
}
private int countHeight(TreeNode node, int number)
{
    if(node != null && node.getNumber() == number)
        return 1;
    if(number < node.getNumber())
       return countHeight(node.getLeft()) + 1;    
    else                                          
       return countHeight(node.getRight()) + 1;
}
```